# Stop FlexSlider slides displaying below each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I have a WordPress site: http://sportpazel.com/item/peak-khalij/

In this page I have a flex slider. The slides stack below each other.

This is an example of what I want instead: http://javothemes.com/directory/demo2/item/international-delivery-service/

How can I fix it using developer tools?

Comment: This a normal demo of what I want to be:
http://javothemes.com/directory/demo2/item/international-delivery-service/

Comment: You should include everything needed to reproduce the problem in your question, including the code you're using (just edit your main post to add that in), so it's easier for others to understand your problem.

Comment: @Aurora0001 The problem is I'm not good at code and programming. I need somebody to discover the problem.